# How to open a device lock programmatically in android?

Tags: android

I can lock my device with below code like

// Initialize Device Policy Manager service and our receiver class

```
devicePolicyManager =(DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
demoDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, DemoDeviceAdminReceiver.class);

devicePolicyManager.lockNow();
```

But once i did it (means lock my device in android by above code ) how can i open this lock programmatically in android whenever i required ? To lock a device i used background service so is there any solution to create any services to re-open a lock of my device ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
//Get the window from the context
WindowManager wm = Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

//Unlock
//http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow()
Window window = getWindow();  
window.addFlags(wm.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE), "TAG");
 wakeLock.acquire();
 wakeLock.release();
```

I used this working for me.